# I have a very weird Virtualbox error and I don't know what it means

Tags: macos, virtualbox

Basically, I have OS X in a VM on Virtualbox and when I put the screen in scaled mode (old 1366x768 laptop), I get the following error that doesn't seem to affect performance, since it has always been SLOW with this VM:
`Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Mac Os Sierra.`

Failed to get a console object from the direct session (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_VM_ERROR (0x80BB0003)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}